# How to resolve Error in karma unit testing: Can not load "Chrome"..?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am getting my head around karma unit testing, I just installed this for my angular app in osx:

```
# Install Karma:
$ npm install karma --save-dev

# Install plugins that your project needs:
$ npm install karma-jasmine karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev
```

My karma config is generated with karma init and contains this:

```
 plugins: [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine'
        ],
```

However when I run karma start I get:

```
 Can not load "Chrome", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
```

How can I fix this?

This is the config file:

```
//jshint strict: false
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: './app',

    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'components/**/*.js',
      'view*/**/*.js'
    ],

    autoWatch: true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    plugins: [
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-firefox-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-junit-reporter'
    ],

    junitReporter: {
      outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
      suite: 'unit'
    }

  });
};
```

Comment: Can you post your entire karma.conf?

Answer (score -1):

Just Run the following npm install command to install chrome launcher. no need to add plugin inside the conf file

```
npm i karma-firefox-launcher karma-junit-reporter karma-opera-launcher karma-ie-launcher karma-jasmine karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev
```

Comment: The user already said they installed `karma-jasmine karma-chrome-launcher`. Your answer installs some extra browsers, but does not address the problem.